# insert com select caso o campo seja null

Tags: java, oracle

Tenho hoje esse INSERT no JAVA rodando mas preciso implementar uma nova rotina:

```
            public void gravarLogAbonoUnificado(TbLogAbonClickUnic entity,
            RetornoAuxDto auxDto) {


            STRING SQL = "INSERT INTO" +
            "TB_LOG_ABON_CLIK_UNIC" +
            "(NR_SEQU_LOG_LOG_CLICK_UNIC, NR_SEQU_TIPO_MOTI, CD_PODR) +
            "VALUES (?,?,?)";

            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(hql);

            Query.setParameter(1, entity.getTbLogEntrClickUnic().
            getNrSequeLogClikUnic()).

            Query.setParameter(2, (long) auxDto.getCodRetorno());

            //ESSE MEU CAMPO SE VIER NULL, PRECISA QUE SEJA INSERIDO //
              Query.setParameter(3, (long) auxDto.getCodRetorno());

            query.executeUpdate;
```

Se o meu campo CD_PODR for NULL ele deve fazer a inserção com esse select:

```
                  select p.nr_seque_item_podr from
            tb_tipo_grup_podr g,
            tb_tipo_item_podr p,
            where
            g.nr_seque_grup_podr = p.nr_seq_grup_podr and
            g.sg_grup_podr = '09'
            and
            p.sg_item_podr = '01'
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bruno, neste caso você pode fazer uma verificação antes do insert, se o valor que vai passar no values correspondente a coluna "CD_PODR" for NULL, você realizar o seguinte insert:

```
STRING SQL = "INSERT INTO" +
        "TB_LOG_ABON_CLIK_UNIC" +
        "(NR_SEQU_LOG_LOG_CLICK_UNIC, NR_SEQU_TIPO_MOTI, CD_PODR)" +
        "(select CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, p.nr_seque_item_podr " +
        "  from tb_tipo_grup_podr g," +
        "       tb_tipo_item_podr p," +
        "  where" +
        "   g.nr_seque_grup_podr = p.nr_seq_grup_podr " +
        "   and g.sg_grup_podr = '09'" +
        "   and p.sg_item_podr = '01'"
```

Para realizar um insert através de um select, no próprio select você deve retornar todos os campos que são esperados para serem inseridos.
Coloquei os "CAMPOS" representando que você tem essas informações em seu select, caso não tenha e queria utilizar o que você esta recebendo em seu método, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira esse trecho:

```
"(select" + VCAMPO1 + VCAMPO2 + VCAMPO3 + "p.nr_seque_item_podr " +
```

Aqui coloquei os "VCAMPOS" como campos do seu código e caso o seu campo CD_PODR seja DIFERENTE DE NULL, você realiza o insert que faz hoje.